# cassandra spark connector works from spark shell but fails in zeppelin

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, apache-zeppelin

I am able to run query using spark shell and spark-cassandra connect driver. But the same command fails from zeppelin. Is there a version of Zeppelin that works well with cassandra connector.

Env
hadoop 2.6.0
spark 1.6.0
zeppelin 0.5.6 incubating.

**command**

```
  import com.datastax.spark.connector._, org.apache.spark.SparkContext, org.apache.spark.SparkContext._, org.apache.spark.SparkConf
    sc.stop 
    val conf = new SparkConf(true).set("spark.cassandra.connection.host", "localhost")
    val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
    val test_spark_rdd = sc.cassandraTable("dev", "emp")
    test_spark_rdd.first

Error
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Detected Guava issue #1635 which indicates that a version of Guava less than 16.01 is in use.  This introduces codec resolution issues and potentially other incompatibility issues in the driver.  Please upgrade to Guava 16.01 or later.
    at com.datastax.driver.core.SanityChecks.checkGuava(SanityChecks.java:62)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.SanityChecks.check(SanityChecks.java:36)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster.<clinit>(Cluster.java:67)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.DefaultConnectionFactory$.clusterBuilder(CassandraConnectionFactory.scala:35)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.DefaultConnectionFactory$.createCluster(CassandraConnectionFactory.scala:87)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.CassandraConnector$.com$datastax$spark$connector$cql$CassandraConnector$$createSession(CassandraConnector.scala:153)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.CassandraConnector$$anonfun$2.apply(CassandraConnector.scala:148)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.CassandraConnector$$anonfun$2.apply(CassandraConnector.scala:148)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.RefCountedCache.createNewValueAndKeys(RefCountedCache.scala:31)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.RefCountedCache.acquire(RefCountedCache.scala:56)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.CassandraConnector.openSession(CassandraConnector.scala:81)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.CassandraConnector.withSessionDo(CassandraConnector.scala:109)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.CassandraConnector.withClusterDo(CassandraConnector.scala:120)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.Schema$.fromCassandra(Schema.scala:254)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.rdd.CassandraTableRowReaderProvider$class.tableDef(CassandraTableRowReaderProvider.scala:51)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.rdd.CassandraTableScanRDD.tableDef$lzycompute(CassandraTableScanRDD.scala:59)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.rdd.CassandraTableScanRDD.tableDef(CassandraTableScanRDD.scala:59)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.rdd.CassandraTableRowReaderProvider$class.verify(CassandraTableRowReaderProvider.scala:146)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.rdd.CassandraTableScanRDD.verify(CassandraTableScanRDD.scala:59)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.rdd.CassandraTableScanRDD.getPartitions(CassandraTableScanRDD.scala:143)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:239)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:237)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:120)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.partitions(RDD.scala:237)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$take$1.apply(RDD.scala:1293)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:150)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:111)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:316)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.take(RDD.scala:1288)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.rdd.CassandraRDD.take(CassandraRDD.scala:121)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.rdd.CassandraRDD.take(CassandraRDD.scala:122)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$first$1.apply(RDD.scala:1328)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:150)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:111)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:316)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.first(RDD.scala:1327)
    at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:42)
    at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:47)
    at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:49)
    at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:51)
    at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:53)
    at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:55)
    at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:57)
    at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:59)
    at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:61)
    at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:63)
    at $iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:65)
    at $iwC.<init>(<console>:67)
    at <init>(<console>:69)
    at .<init>(<console>:73)
    at .<clinit>(<console>)
    at .<init>(<console>:7)
    at .<clinit>(<console>)
    at $print(<console>)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain$ReadEvalPrint.call(SparkIMain.scala:1065)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain$Request.loadAndRun(SparkIMain.scala:1346)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain.loadAndRunReq$1(SparkIMain.scala:840)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain.interpret(SparkIMain.scala:871)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain.interpret(SparkIMain.scala:819)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.spark.SparkInterpreter.interpretInput(SparkInterpreter.java:709)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.spark.SparkInterpreter.interpret(SparkInterpreter.java:674)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.spark.SparkInterpreter.interpret(SparkInterpreter.java:667)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.ClassloaderInterpreter.interpret(ClassloaderInterpreter.java:57)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.LazyOpenInterpreter.interpret(LazyOpenInterpreter.java:93)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.remote.RemoteInterpreterServer$InterpretJob.jobRun(RemoteInterpreterServer.java:300)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.scheduler.Job.run(Job.java:169)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.scheduler.FIFOScheduler$1.run(FIFOScheduler.java:134)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

The following jars were loaded by spark

```
/Users/user/Downloads/hadoop-2.6.0/share/hadoop/common/lib/commons-beanutils-1.7.0.jar  System Classpath
/Users/user/Downloads/hadoop-2.6.0/share/hadoop/common/lib/commons-logging-1.1.3.jar    System Classpath
/Users/user/Downloads/hadoop-2.6.0/share/hadoop/yarn/hadoop-yarn-api-2.6.0.jar  System Classpath
/Users/user/Downloads/hadoop-2.6.0/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/jetty-util-6.1.26.jar  System Classpath
/Users/user/Downloads/hadoop-2.6.0/share/hadoop/common/lib/protobuf-java-2.5.0.jar  System Classpath
/Users/user/Downloads/hadoop-2.6.0/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/snappy-java-1.0.4.1.jar   System Classpath
/Users/user/Downloads/hadoop-2.6.0/share/hadoop/common/lib/api-util-1.0.0-M20.jar   System Classpath
/Users/user/Downloads/hadoop-2.6.0/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/javax.inject-1.jar    System Classpath
/Users/user/Downloads/hadoop-2.6.0/share/hadoop/common/lib/htrace-core-3.0.4.jar    System Classpath
/Users/user/Downloads/hadoop-2.6.0/share/hadoop/common/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.5.jar  System Classpath
/Users/user/Downloads/hadoop-2.6.0/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/aopalliance-1.0.jar    System Classpath
/Users/user/Downloads/hadoop-2.6.0/share/hadoop/common/lib/commons-digester-1.8.jar System Classpath
/Users/user/Downloads/hadoop-2.6.0/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/jetty-util-6.1.26.jar  System Classpath
/Users/user/Downloads/hadoop-2.6.0/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/jsr305-1.3.9.jar   System Classpath
/Users/user/Downloads/hadoop-2.6.0/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/jline-0.9.94.jar   System Classpath
/Users/user/Downloads/hadoop-2.6.0/share/hadoop/common/lib/jetty-6.1.26.jar System Classpath
/Users/user/Downloads/hadoop-2.6.0/share/hadoop/common/lib/api-asn1-api-1.0.0-M20.jar   System Classpath
http://192.168.99.1:51164/jars/com.twitter_jsr166e-1.1.0.jar    Added By User
/Users/user/Downloads/hadoop-2.6.0/share/hadoop/mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-client-app-2.6.0.jar System Classpath
/Users/user/Downloads/hadoop-2.6.0/share/hadoop/common/lib/activation-1.1.jar   System Classpath
/Users/user/Downloads/hadoop-2.6.0/share/hadoop/yarn/hadoop-yarn-server-common-2.6.0.jar    System Classpath
/Users/user/Downloads/hadoop-2.6.0/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/guava-18.0.jar System Classpath
/Users/user/Downloads/hadoop-2.6.0/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/leveldbjni-all-1.8.jar System Classpath
/Users/user/Downloads/hadoop-2.6.0/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/jersey-core-1.9.jar   System Classpath
/Users/user/Downloads/hadoop-2.6.0/share/hadoop/yarn/hadoop-yarn-common-2.6.0.jar   System Classpath
/Users/user/Downloads/hadoop-2.6.0/share/hadoop/common/lib/xmlenc-0.52.jar  System Classpath
/Users/user/Downloads/hadoop-2.6.0/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/aopalliance-1.0.jar   System Classpath
/Users/user/Downloads/hadoop-2.6.0/share/hadoop/yarn/hadoop-yarn-server-tests-2.6.0.jar System Classpath
/Users/user/Downloads/hadoop-2.6.0/share/hadoop/common/lib/commons-collections-3.2.1.jar    System Classpath
/Users/user/Downloads/hadoop-2.6.0/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/jersey-json-1.9.jar    System Classpath
/Users/user/Downloads/hadoop-2.6.0/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/paranamer-2.3.jar System Classpath
/Users/user/Downloads/hadoop-2.6.0/share/hadoop/common/lib/paranamer-2.3.jar    System Classpath
http://192.168.99.1:51164/jars/com.datastax.cassandra_cassandra-driver-core-3.0.0.jar   Added By User
/Users/user/Downloads/hadoop-2.6.0/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/jackson-core-asl-1.9.13.jar    System Classpath
/Users/user/Downloads/hadoop-2.6.0/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/commons-logging-1.1.3.jar  System Classpath
/Users/user/Downloads/hadoop-2.6.0/share/hadoop/common/lib/apacheds-i18n-2.0.0-M15.jar  System Classpath
/Users/user/Downloads/hadoop-2.6.0/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/jersey-client-1.9.jar  System Classpath
/Users/user/Downloads/hadoop-2.6.0/share/hadoop/common/lib/commons-configuration-1.6.jar    System Classpath
/Users/user/Downloads/hadoop-2.6.0/share/hadoop/mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-client-hs-plugins-2.6.0.jar  System Classpath
/Users/user/Downloads/hadoop-2.6.0/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/commons-io-2.4.jar System Classpath
/Users/user/Downloads/hadoop-2.6.0/share/hadoop/common/lib/jsp-api-2.1.jar  System Classpath
/Users/user/Downloads/hadoop-2.6.0/share/hadoop/common/lib/log4j-1.2.17.jar System Classpath
/Users/user/Downloads/hadoop-2.6.0/share/hadoop/common/hadoop-nfs-2.6.0.jar System Classpath
/Users/user/Downloads/hadoop-2.6.0/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/commons-logging-1.1.3.jar  System Classpath
/Users/user/Downloads/hadoop-2.6.0/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/commons-collections-3.2.1.jar  System Classpath
/Users/user/Downloads/hadoop-2.6.0/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/jersey-guice-1.9.jar  System Classpath
/Users/user/Downloads/hadoop-2.6.0/share/hadoop/common/lib/curator-client-2.6.0.jar System Classpath
/Users/user/Downloads/hadoop-2.6.0/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/commons-httpclient-3.1.jar System Classpath
/Users/user/Downloads/hadoop-2.6.0/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/jackson-xc-1.9.13.jar  System Classpath
/Users/user/Downloads/hadoop-2.6.0/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/netty-3.6.2.Final.jar  System Classpath
http://192.168.99.1:51164/jars/joda-time_joda-time-2.3.jar  Added By User
/Users/user/Downloads/hadoop-2.6.0/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/hadoop-annotations-2.6.0.jar  System Classpath
/Users/user/Downloads/hadoop-2.6.0/share/hadoop/common/lib/commons-math3-3.1.1.jar  System Classpath
/Users/user/Downloads/hadoop-2.6.0/share/hadoop/common/lib/jersey-server-1.9.jar    System Classpath
/Users/user/Downloads/hadoop-2.6.0/share/hadoop/yarn/hadoop-yarn-server-nodemanager-2.6.0.jar   System Classpath
/Users/user/Downloads/hadoop-2.6.0/share/hadoop/mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-examples-2.6.0.jar   System Classpath
/Users/user/Downloads/hadoop-2.6.0/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/commons-codec-1.4.jar  System Classpath
http://192.168.99.1:51164/jars/io.netty_netty-common-4.0.33.Final.jar   Added By User
http://192.168.99.1:51164/jars/io.netty_netty-codec-4.0.33.Final.jar    Added By User
/Users/user/Downloads/hadoop-2.6.0/share/hadoop/common/lib/jasper-compiler-5.5.23.jar   System Classpath
/Users/user/Downloads/hadoop-2.6.0/share/hadoop/common/lib/zookeeper-3.4.6.jar  System Classpath
/Users/user/Downloads/hadoop-2.6.0/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/protobuf-java-2.5.0.jar    System Classpath
http://192.168.99.1:51164/jars/io.netty_netty-transport-4.0.33.Final.jar    Added By User
/Users/user/Downloads/hadoop-2.6.0/etc/hadoop/  System Classpath
/Users/user/Downloads/hadoop-2.6.0/share/hadoop/common/lib/jackson-mapper-asl-1.9.13.jar    System Classpath
/Users/user/Downloads/hadoop-2.6.0/share/hadoop/common/lib/jetty-util-6.1.26.jar    System Classpath
/Users/user/Downloads/hadoop-2.6.0/share/hadoop/common/lib/junit-4.11.jar   System Classpath
/Users/user/Downloads/hadoop-2.6.0/share/hadoop/common/lib/hadoop-auth-2.6.0.jar    System Classpath
/Users/user/Downloads/hadoop-2.6.0/share/hadoop/common/lib/commons-cli-1.2.jar  System Classpath
/Users/user/Downloads/hadoop-2.6.0/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/protobuf-java-2.5.0.jar   System Classpath
/Users/user/Downloads/hadoop-2.6.0/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/netty-3.6.2.Final.jar System Classpath
http://192.168.99.1:51164/jars/io.dropwizard.metrics_metrics-core-3.1.2.jar Added By User
/Users/user/Downloads/hadoop-2.6.0/share/hadoop/common/lib/hadoop-annotations-2.6.0.jar System Classpath
/Users/user/Downloads/hadoop-2.6.0/share/hadoop/hdfs/hadoop-hdfs-nfs-2.6.0.jar  System Classpath
/Users/user/Downloads/hadoop-2.6.0/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/commons-codec-1.4.jar  System Classpath
/Users/user/Downloads/hadoop-2.6.0/share/hadoop/yarn/hadoop-yarn-applications-unmanaged-am-launcher-2.6.0.jar   System Classpath
/Users/user/Downloads/hadoop-2.6.0/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/commons-io-2.4.jar    System Classpath
/Users/user/Downloads/hadoop-2.6.0/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/jersey-guice-1.9.jar   System Classpath
/Users/user/Downloads/hadoop-2.6.0/share/hadoop/common/lib/commons-codec-1.4.jar    System Classpath
/Users/user/Downloads/hadoop-2.6.0/share/hadoop/common/lib/commons-lang-2.6.jar System Classpath
/Users/user/Downloads/hadoop-2.6.0/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/xmlenc-0.52.jar    System Classpath
/Users/user/Downloads/hadoop-2.6.0/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/javax.inject-1.jar System Classpath
/Users/user/Downloads/hadoop-2.6.0/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/guice-3.0.jar System Classpath
/Users/user/Downloads/hadoop-2.6.0/share/hadoop/yarn/hadoop-yarn-registry-2.6.0.jar System Classpath
/Users/user/Downloads/hadoop-2.6.0/share/hadoop/yarn/hadoop-yarn-server-applicationhistoryservice-2.6.0.jar System Classpath
/Users/user/Downloads/hadoop-2.6.0/share/hadoop/mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-client-common-2.6.0.jar  System Classpath
/Users/user/Downloads/hadoop-2.6.0/share/hadoop/common/lib/commons-httpclient-3.1.jar   System Classpath
/Users/user/Downloads/hadoop-2.6.0/share/hadoop/yarn/hadoop-yarn-applications-distributedshell-2.6.0.jar    System Classpath
/Users/user/Downloads/hadoop-2.6.0/share/hadoop/common/lib/jaxb-api-2.2.2.jar   System Classpath
/Users/user/Downloads/hadoop-2.6.0/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/servlet-api-2.5.jar    System Classpath
/Users/user/Downloads/hadoop-2.6.0/share/hadoop/hdfs/   System Classpath
/Users/user/Downloads/hadoop-2.6.0/share/hadoop/common/lib/asm-3.2.jar  System Classpath
/Users/user/Downloads/hadoop-2.6.0/share/hadoop/common/lib/xz-1.0.jar   System Classpath
/Users/user/Downloads/hadoop-2.6.0/share/hadoop/common/lib/jackson-xc-1.9.13.jar    System Classpath
/Users/user/Downloads/hadoop-2.6.0/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/servlet-api-2.5.jar    System Classpath
/Users/user/Downloads/hadoop-2.6.0/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/jersey-core-1.9.jar    System Classpath
/Users/user/Downloads/hadoop-2.6.0/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/asm-3.2.jar   System Classpath
http://192.168.99.1:51164/jars/io.netty_netty-buffer-4.0.33.Final.jar   Added By User
/Users/user/Downloads/hadoop-2.6.0/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/xz-1.0.jar    System Classpath
http://192.168.99.1:51164/jars/org.apache.cassandra_cassandra-clientutil-3.0.2.jar  Added By User
/Users/user/Downloads/hadoop-2.6.0/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/jersey-server-1.9.jar System Classpath
/Users/user/Downloads/hadoop-2.6.0/share/hadoop/mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-client-core-2.6.0.jar    System Classpath
http://192.168.99.1:51164/jars/com.google.guava_guava-16.0.1.jar    Added By User
/Users/user/Downloads/hadoop-2.6.0/share/hadoop/common/lib/jersey-core-1.9.jar  System Classpath
/Users/user/Downloads/hadoop-2.6.0/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/leveldbjni-all-1.8.jar    System Classpath
/Users/user/Downloads/hadoop-2.6.0/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/commons-compress-1.4.1.jar System Classpath
/Users/user/Downloads/hadoop-2.6.0/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/jackson-mapper-asl-1.9.13.jar  System Classpath
/Users/user/Downloads/hadoop-2.6.0/share/hadoop/common/lib/avro-1.7.4.jar   System Classpath
/Users/user/Downloads/hadoop-2.6.0/share/hadoop/common/lib/snappy-java-1.0.4.1.jar  System Classpath
/Users/user/Downloads/hadoop-2.6.0/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/jetty-6.1.26.jar   System Classpath
/Users/user/Downloads/hadoop-2.6.0/share/hadoop/common/lib/commons-compress-1.4.1.jar   System Classpath
/Users/user/Downloads/hadoop-2.6.0/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/jersey-server-1.9.jar  System Classpath
/Users/user/Downloads/hadoop-2.6.0/share/hadoop/common/lib/jackson-jaxrs-1.9.13.jar System Classpath
/Users/user/Downloads/zeppelin-0.5.6-incubating-bin-all/interpreter/spark/zeppelin-spark-0.5.6-incubating.jar   System Classpath
/Users/user/Downloads/hadoop-2.6.0/contrib/capacity-scheduler/*.jar System Classpath
http://192.168.99.1:51164/jars/datastax_spark-cassandra-connector-1.5.1-s_2.10.jar  Added By User
/Users/user/Downloads/hadoop-2.6.0/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/guava-18.0.jar System Classpath
/Users/user/Downloads/hadoop-2.6.0/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/htrace-core-3.0.4.jar  System Classpath
/Users/user/Downloads/hadoop-2.6.0/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/hamcrest-core-1.3.jar System Classpath
/Users/user/Downloads/hadoop-2.6.0/share/hadoop/common/lib/slf4j-api-1.7.5.jar  System Classpath
/Users/user/Downloads/hadoop-2.6.0/share/hadoop/common/lib/httpcore-4.2.5.jar   System Classpath
/Users/user/Downloads/hadoop-2.6.0/share/hadoop/common/lib/jsch-0.1.42.jar  System Classpath
/Users/user/Downloads/hadoop-2.6.0/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/guice-servlet-3.0.jar System Classpath
/Users/user/jars/   System Classpath
/Users/user/Downloads/hadoop-2.6.0/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/log4j-1.2.17.jar   System Classpath
/Users/user/Downloads/hadoop-2.6.0/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/asm-3.2.jar    System Classpath
http://192.168.99.1:51164/jars/org.joda_joda-convert-1.2.jar    Added By User
/Users/user/Downloads/hadoop-2.6.0/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/avro-1.7.4.jar    System Classpath
/Users/user/Downloads/hadoop-2.6.0/share/hadoop/common/lib/jettison-1.1.jar System Classpath
/Users/user/Downloads/hadoop-2.6.0/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/jersey-server-1.9.jar  System Classpath
/Users/user/Downloads/hadoop-2.6.0/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/jackson-core-asl-1.9.13.jar   System Classpath
/Users/user/Downloads/hadoop-2.6.0/share/hadoop/common/lib/jsr305-1.3.9.jar System Classpath
/Users/user/Downloads/hadoop-2.6.0/share/hadoop/common/lib/jaxb-impl-2.2.3-1.jar    System Classpath
/Users/user/Downloads/hadoop-2.6.0/share/hadoop/common/lib/commons-net-3.1.jar  System Classpath
/Users/user/Downloads/hadoop-2.6.0/share/hadoop/common/hadoop-common-2.6.0.jar  System Classpath
/Users/user/Downloads/hadoop-2.6.0/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/commons-el-1.0.jar System Classpath
/Users/user/Downloads/hadoop-2.6.0/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/guice-3.0.jar  System Classpath
/Users/user/Downloads/hadoop-2.6.0/share/hadoop/mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-client-jobclient-2.6.0-tests.jar System Classpath
/Users/user/Downloads/hadoop-2.6.0/share/hadoop/common/lib/jasper-runtime-5.5.23.jar    System Classpath
/Users/user/Downloads/hadoop-2.6.0/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/jackson-core-asl-1.9.13.jar    System Classpath
/Users/user/Downloads/spark-1.6.0-bin-without-hadoop/lib/spark-assembly-1.6.0-hadoop2.2.0.jar   System Classpath
/Users/user/Downloads/hadoop-2.6.0/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/commons-cli-1.2.jar    System Classpath
/Users/user/Downloads/hadoop-2.6.0/share/hadoop/common/lib/commons-io-2.4.jar   System Classpath
http://192.168.99.1:51164/jars/org.apache.commons_commons-lang3-3.3.2.jar   Added By User
/Users/user/Downloads/hadoop-2.6.0/share/hadoop/common/lib/httpclient-4.2.5.jar System Classpath
/Users/user/Downloads/hadoop-2.6.0/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/stax-api-1.0-2.jar System Classpath
/Users/user/Downloads/hadoop-2.6.0/share/hadoop/common/lib/java-xmlbuilder-0.4.jar  System Classpath
/Users/user/Downloads/hadoop-2.6.0/share/hadoop/yarn/hadoop-yarn-server-web-proxy-2.6.0.jar System Classpath
/Users/user/Downloads/hadoop-2.6.0/share/hadoop/hdfs/hadoop-hdfs-2.6.0.jar  System Classpath
/Users/user/Downloads/hadoop-2.6.0/share/hadoop/mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-client-shuffle-2.6.0.jar System Classpath
/Users/user/Downloads/hadoop-2.6.0/share/hadoop/common/hadoop-common-2.6.0-tests.jar    System Classpath
/Users/user/Downloads/hadoop-2.6.0/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/jackson-mapper-asl-1.9.13.jar  System Classpath
/Users/user/Downloads/hadoop-2.6.0/share/hadoop/common/lib/hamcrest-core-1.3.jar    System Classpath
/Users/user/Downloads/hadoop-2.6.0/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/xercesImpl-2.9.1.jar   System Classpath
/Users/user/Downloads/hadoop-2.6.0/share/hadoop/common/lib/curator-framework-2.6.0.jar  System Classpath
/Users/user/Downloads/hadoop-2.6.0/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/xml-apis-1.3.04.jar    System Classpath
/Users/user/Downloads/spark-1.6.0-bin-without-hadoop/conf/  System Classpath
/Users/user/Downloads/hadoop-2.6.0/share/hadoop/common/lib/netty-3.6.2.Final.jar    System Classpath
/Users/user/Downloads/hadoop-2.6.0/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/jasper-runtime-5.5.23.jar  System Classpath
http://192.168.99.1:51164/jars/org.scala-lang_scala-reflect-2.10.5.jar  Added By User
/Users/user/Downloads/hadoop-2.6.0/share/hadoop/common/lib/jackson-core-asl-1.9.13.jar  System Classpath
http://192.168.99.1:51164/jars/io.netty_netty-handler-4.0.33.Final.jar  Added By User
/Users/user/Downloads/hadoop-2.6.0/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/activation-1.1.jar System Classpath
/Users/user/Downloads/hadoop-2.6.0/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/commons-io-2.4.jar System Classpath
/Users/user/Downloads/hadoop-2.6.0/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/jsr305-1.3.9.jar   System Classpath
/Users/user/Downloads/hadoop-2.6.0/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/log4j-1.2.17.jar   System Classpath
/Users/user/Downloads/hadoop-2.6.0/share/hadoop/common/lib/gson-2.2.4.jar   System Classpath
/Users/user/Downloads/hadoop-2.6.0/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/jersey-core-1.9.jar    System Classpath
/Users/user/Downloads/hadoop-2.6.0/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/jackson-jaxrs-1.9.13.jar   System Classpath
/Users/user/Downloads/hadoop-2.6.0/share/hadoop/yarn/hadoop-yarn-client-2.6.0.jar   System Classpath
/Users/user/Downloads/hadoop-2.6.0/share/hadoop/common/lib/jersey-json-1.9.jar  System Classpath
/Users/user/Downloads/hadoop-2.6.0/share/hadoop/hdfs/hadoop-hdfs-2.6.0-tests.jar    System Classpath
/Users/user/Downloads/hadoop-2.6.0/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/commons-lang-2.6.jar   System Classpath
/Users/user/Downloads/hadoop-2.6.0/share/hadoop/common/lib/apacheds-kerberos-codec-2.0.0-M15.jar    System Classpath
/Users/user/Downloads/hadoop-2.6.0/share/hadoop/mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-client-jobclient-2.6.0.jar   System Classpath
/Users/user/Downloads/hadoop-2.6.0/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/asm-3.2.jar    System Classpath
/Users/user/Downloads/hadoop-2.6.0/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/junit-4.11.jar    System Classpath
/Users/user/Downloads/hadoop-2.6.0/share/hadoop/common/lib/curator-recipes-2.6.0.jar    System Classpath
/Users/user/Downloads/hadoop-2.6.0/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/protobuf-java-2.5.0.jar    System Classpath
/Users/user/Downloads/hadoop-2.6.0/share/hadoop/common/lib/commons-beanutils-core-1.8.0.jar System Classpath
/Users/user/Downloads/hadoop-2.6.0/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/commons-cli-1.2.jar    System Classpath
/Users/user/Downloads/hadoop-2.6.0/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/commons-lang-2.6.jar   System Classpath
/Users/user/Downloads/hadoop-2.6.0/share/hadoop/common/lib/commons-el-1.0.jar   System Classpath
/Users/user/Downloads/hadoop-2.6.0/share/hadoop/yarn/hadoop-yarn-server-resourcemanager-2.6.0.jar   System Classpath
/Users/user/Downloads/hadoop-2.6.0/share/hadoop/common/lib/mockito-all-1.8.5.jar    System Classpath
/Users/user/Downloads/hadoop-2.6.0/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/commons-daemon-1.0.13.jar  System Classpath
/Users/user/Downloads/hadoop-2.6.0/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/jettison-1.1.jar   System Classpath
/Users/user/Downloads/hadoop-2.6.0/share/hadoop/common/lib/stax-api-1.0-2.jar   System Classpath
/Users/user/Downloads/hadoop-2.6.0/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/zookeeper-3.4.6.jar    System Classpath
/Users/user/Downloads/hadoop-2.6.0/share/hadoop/common/lib/jets3t-0.9.0.jar System Classpath
/Users/user/Downloads/hadoop-2.6.0/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/commons-compress-1.4.1.jar    System Classpath
/Users/user/Downloads/hadoop-2.6.0/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/guice-servlet-3.0.jar  System Classpath
/Users/user/Downloads/hadoop-2.6.0/share/hadoop/common/lib/servlet-api-2.5.jar  System Classpath
http://192.168.99.1:51164/jars/org.slf4j_slf4j-api-1.7.7.jar    Added By User
/Users/user/Downloads/hadoop-2.6.0/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/jaxb-api-2.2.2.jar System Classpath
http://192.168.99.1:51164/jars/zeppelin-spark-0.5.6-incubating.jar  Added By User
/Users/user/Downloads/hadoop-2.6.0/share/hadoop/common/lib/guava-18.0.jar   System Classpath
/Users/user/Downloads/hadoop-2.6.0/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/jsp-api-2.1.jar    System Classpath
/Users/user/Downloads/hadoop-2.6.0/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/xz-1.0.jar System Classpath
/Users/user/Downloads/hadoop-2.6.0/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/jackson-mapper-asl-1.9.13.jar System Classpath
/Users/user/Downloads/hadoop-2.6.0/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/jetty-6.1.26.jar   System Classpath
/Users/user/Downloads/hadoop-2.6.0/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/log4j-1.2.17.jar  System Classpath
/Users/user/Downloads/hadoop-2.6.0/share/hadoop/mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-client-hs-2.6.0.jar  System Classpath
/Users/user/Downloads/hadoop-2.6.0/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/jaxb-impl-2.2.3-1.jar  System Classpath
/Users/user/Downloads/hadoop-2.6.0/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/netty-3.6.2.Final.jar  System Classpath
```

Comment: It clearly says Guava version error.  http://192.168.99.1:51164/jars/com.google.guava_guava-16.0.1.jar    Added By User

Comment: Yes Thank you. I did notice that, I worded my question correctly. The issue is that spark works as it is from spark-submit or spark-shell. The specific issue is noticed only when connecting from zeppelin.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a problem with zeppelin. I have opened a JIRA with them https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/ZEPPELIN-1205. The issue is resolved by upgrading the guava version in spark interpreter in zeppelin.

The issue is resolved once the guava version is changed from 14.0.1 to 16.0.1 in zeppelin/spark/pom.xml and then compiled using

`mvn clean package -DskipTests -Pcassandra-spark-1.5 -Phadoop-2.6`